# Permutations: Probability of a woman in the top 4

Tags: probability, permutations

"There are 10 contestants in an archery competition. 4 of the contestants are women. Prizes are awarded to the top 4 competitors. What is the probability that at least one woman finishes in the first 4 places."

I've been going around in circles a little bit with this one, as it is from a draft textbook that has quite a few incorrect answers. I get:

$P_4^{10}=5040$ for the total ways of arranging the top 4.

$P_4^6=360$ for the number of ways of arranging a top 4 with no women.

$P_4^{10}-P_4^6=4680$ for the number of ways of arranging a top 4 with at least one woman.

So the probability of at least one woman finishing in the top 10 is $4680/5040$ 
 $=13/14$

However, the text book says $1/14$.

Apologies if I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: The probability of no woman be in the top 4 is 1/14, and thus the probability of at least one woman be in the top 4 is 13/14. I think you are right.

Comment: I think you're right if all outcomes of the competition are equally likely.$$1-\frac{ {6}\choose{4} }{ {10}\choose{4}} = 13/14$$

Answer (score 1):

You are definately right. The probability that there's no woman in the top 4 (let's call it $A$) is 
$$P(A) = \frac{6*5*4*3}{10*9*8*7}=\frac{1}{14}.$$
So the probability that there's at least one woman in the top 4 is
$$P(A')=1-P(A)=\frac{13}{14}.$$

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll make a note in the book!